# No Image on IE browser when using Image Button or Button Field in Grid View

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, imagebutton, buttonfield

Does anyone know why I'm encountering this issue using IE (all version) as browser? The image works perfectly on Chrome but not on IE.

Here is an example screenshot of what I'm talking about:

**IE:**

[image: IE]

And when I try this using Chrome it works as expected.

**Chrome:**

[image: chrome]

and here is the code I use which I also found on the Internet.

```
<asp:GridView ID="gvJobs" runat="server" OnRowCommand="gvJobs_RowCommand">
    <Columns>
        <%--<asp:ButtonField ButtonType="Image" CommandName="btnExtract_Click" ImageUrl="~/images/icons/ExcelLogo.png" CausesValidation="false" />--%>
        <asp:TemplateField>
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:ImageButton ID="btnExtractId" AutoPostback="true" runat="server" 
                    ToolTip="Calibration Form" CommandName="btnExtract_Click" CausesValidation="false" ImageUrl="~/images/icons/ExcelLogo.png" /> 
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:HyperLinkField HeaderText="Job Reference" DataTextField="JobReference" DataNavigateUrlFields="JobId" DataNavigateUrlFormatString="job.aspx?jobid={0}" />
        <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Job Type" DataField="JobTypeName" />
        <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Business Unit" DataField="BusinessUnitName" />
        <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Client" DataField="ClientFullname" />           
        <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Planned Completion Date" DataField="PlannedCompletionDate" DataFormatString="{0:dd/MM/yyyy}" />
        <asp:HyperLinkField HeaderText="Parent Job" DataTextField="ParentJobReference" DataNavigateUrlFields="ParentJobId" DataNavigateUrlFormatString="job.aspx?jobid={0}" Visible="false" />
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

I already tried the two controls but still no luck on the issue. I also look for a solution on the Internet but it does not help me solve my problem.

Thanks in advance to someone who can help me.

Answer (score 1):

i have tried your code with static values and its working fine.
you need to clear cache of internet Explorer i guess. or press `ctrl + F5`

Either its cached on chrome or IE also you need to check file exist or not after clearing cache.

here we go with the screenshot using your code.
[image]

do let me know if you need any help

Comment: Thanks for the help @Manoj Bhardwaj, but still got the same issue. It just like the image is missing in IE and still don't know why as this is working in Chrome. Do you have any other suggestions? thanks again.

Comment: can you please share your screen or screen shot after inspecting in developer tool.  my gmail id is manoj.creatives@gmail.com

Comment: Hi @Manoj Bhardwaj, I already sent it to your gmail account. Thanks :)

Comment: did you clear the cache of your chrome browser?  i need to look into the code live. can you share your skype id?

Comment: yes, I already cleared all the cache from both Browser. sorry but I don't think our Skype can have connection outside of our network. But I can also give you the Developer Tool on Chrome.

Comment: sure share that because i run your code on my machine and its working on both browsers. so i need to look into your browsers.

Comment: Seems fine. Can you please do me a favour do download one .PNG file which is opening on IE from Google and then give reference of it. Just to test. If that works then there is some problem with image. Chrome is an advance browser that's why it has capabilities to open broken files but IE not.

Comment: Hi, @Manoj Bhardway. I already solve my issue by using other image on the application. You're right, I have a problem with the image I get using chrome. Maybe that Image is not working on IE. Thanks for the help appreciate it. :)